# Dereferencing char into a struct

Tags: nrf24l01+, pointer

I am sending some data over an NRF24 link, using the [RF24Network](https://github.com/TMRh20/RF24Network)  library. So far I have only sent numbers, now I also want to send a string, so I have set up my payload struct as

```
struct payload_t {                  // Structure of our payload
   unsigned long data;
   unsigned long datatype;
   char sensorid[20];
   unsigned long counter;
};
```

As far as I do understand, I can not use string here, since I need to know the length of the data I am sending.

At the moment I am using sensors without an internal ID, so in `loop()`, I am calling:

```
 writeToNetwork(voltage,'v',"nosid",packets_sent++);
```

My `writeToNetwork` function is defined as

```
 bool writeToNetwork(unsigned long data,unsigned long type,char sid[20],unsigned long package){
```

and within that, I am setting up the payload with

```
 payload_t payload = { data,type,sid, package };
```

Which gives me an

```
 error: invalid conversion from ‘char*’ to ‘char’ [-fpermissive]
```

Clearly, I have no interest of the address the pointer is referencing, so I need to somehow dereference the `sid` - pointer to get my array into the struct. How can I do that?

Or am I barking up the wrong tree? I tried to transfer the id as a string:

```
#include <string.h>
bool writeToNetwork(unsigned long data,unsigned long type,String sid,unsigned long package){
char sidchar[20];
sid.toCharArray(sidchar,20);
payload_t payload = { data,type,sidchar, package };
```

Which gives me the error

```
array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer
```

Which I do not understand. Doing

```
char sidchar[20]={0};
```

gives me the same error.

Comment: Just to clarify - `I can not use string here` - do you mean a ["string"](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/String) or a ["`String`" object](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/StringObject)? I only ask, because you are using a "string" with `char sensorid[20];`... Also, have I linked to the correct RF24Network library?

Comment: Thanks, wrong library, but I've corrected it. Where you quoted, I did mean "string".

Comment: Best check the payload size. That is 32-bytes which is max for NRF24L01 but the libraries you want to use will needs some of the payload for addressing etc.

Answer (score 4):

In your situation, your best bet is probably to use the standard C function [`strcpy`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/):

```
payload_t payload;
char* source = "abcdef";
strcpy(payload.sensorid, source);
```

Note that source string does not have to be declared as `char source[20]` and can be declared as the rather standard C string `char*`.

Also, since you are limiting the size of the string to be passed in `payload`, you may prefer to use [`strncpy`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncpy/) which will ensure no more than 20 characters get copied:

```
payload_t payload;
char* source = "abcdef";
strncpy(payload.sensorid, source, 20);
// Explicitly add a string termination to the end of string
payload.sensorid[19] = 0;
```

In the snippet above, please notice the last line, it is necessary in the situation where `source` string length is 20 or more non-null characters, as in this case, `strncpy` will copy all 20 characters but will not add the terminating 0 at the end of the string.

Comment: I deleted my comment as I was wrong with the missing `\0`.